# a class in list, after remove list the class's memory will be realeased?

Tags: c#

If I write down this

```
List<ClassA> list = new List<ClassA>()
{
    new ClassA()
};

list.Clear();
```

then there is no way to get that ClassA, so that memory of ClassA will be released or not?

Comment: the .NET runtime is a garbage collecting runtime. the instance will go out of scope, and no references will exist after the call to clear, so it is eligible for collection. *eventually*, memory will actually be released - not immediately though.

Comment: If you're concerned about the space within the list that is allocated to hold the reference, you can shrink the list using [`list.TrimExcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.trimexcess?view=netcore-3.1) after calling `list.Clear()`

Comment: As written, there are no more references to it. If you have any code between those statements that obtains a reference (like: `var myClassInstance = list[0];`), then the memory won't be cleared. Once all references are gone, it will eventually be garbage-collected.

Comment: I got it, thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the initiated ClassA() will be deleted. Meaning that the memory is released.

Comment: ,,,unless something else obtained a reference to it before the list was cleared, like `var class = list[0];`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the memory will be released.

Here's [the source code for the `Clear` method](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/ea1d20c71e7c4402a63be4c275296fc39ab75ebd/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs#L286-L304):

```
// Clears the contents of List.
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public void Clear()
{
    _version++;
    if (RuntimeHelpers.IsReferenceOrContainsReferences<T>())
    {
        int size = _size;
        _size = 0;
        if (size > 0)
        {
            Array.Clear(_items, 0, size); // Clear the elements so that the gc can reclaim the references.
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _size = 0;
    }
}
```